# Crear Autenticación en .net con Google

Tags: c#, autenticación

Estoy haciendo una Aplicación Web utilizando C# y SQL. Mi aplicación utiliza la estructura de capas (Entidades Compartidas, Logica y Persistencia), ASP.NET.

Estoy buscando información que me ayude a crear un Login de Usuario, con autenticación utilizando Google, encontre bastante información al respecto, pero siempre usando MVC, lo cual no es mi caso.

Al no encontrar nada al respecto, mi primer pregunta sería ¿Es posible crear una Autenticación por Google con arquitectura de capas?

y lo segundo ¿Alguien tiene algun sitio o documento en el cual me pueda guiar?

Gracias!